# Create Archive Page with Visual Composer

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, visual-editor

I have a custom post type and have the file created called archive-services.php in my theme. I want this archive page to be represented by a user created page in wp admin. This way the user can create the archive page and modify it. I have the page created in VC too. My issue is that I do not know how to connect them.

Right now I have the domain of the visual composer created page set up as "services" however when I go to the page the content is not loaded even though I have a standard loop setup on the archive-services.php file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WordPress does not offer a way of editing `archive`s. (archive templates are utterly useless in any real life applications, if any cares about my opinion).

You would have to create a theme option/settings page, where you would control the styling of an `archive` template.

But, quicker would be to just not use an `archive` template at all and instead put a `shortcode` into a normal `page`, where you could then use Visual Composer (you can even make your shortcode a VC element).